# Recommended *minimal* elliptic curve library in c

Tags: c, encryption, encryption-asymmetric, elliptic-curve

Any recommendations for a c-library implementing elliptic curve cryptography - the smaller the better.

I know openSSL provides it, but I want something as small as possible. It doesn't need any fancy stuff like constant time encryption / decryption / signing either.

Bonus points for nice-looking code.

Comment: An implementation that does not do constant time encryption/decryption/signing is broken, because it may allow (surprisingly effective) attacks like padding oracle attacks. Constant time operations are a basic feature of a cryptographic library, not a fancy addon.

Comment: @ntoskrnl Sure, but I just want to read the code - so the smaller the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LibTomCrypt](http://libtom.org/?page=features&newsitems=5&whatfile=crypt) has a pretty terse ecc module.